# Avoid Nested for loop

Tags: apex, trigger

Background:

When inserting a contact I have to check if there are any other contacts associated to the same account and its a primary contact to that account is yes, then the new contact cannot be marked as primary. I have written the logic but want to avoid nested loops using Maps, but not sure how to do it.

```
trigger AccConTrg on Contact (after insert, before delete, before Insert,before update, after delete) {
  
    List<Contact> conList = [Select Id, Name, Primary_Contact__c, AccountId from Contact where AccountId != null];
    
    List<Account> accNewList = new List<Account>(); 
    
    if(trigger.isBefore && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)){
         for(Contact con: trigger.new){
            
             for(Contact co: conList){
                 if(con.AccountId == co.AccountId && co.Primary_Contact__c && con.Primary_Contact__c){
                     con.addError('There could be only one Primary contact for each Account');
                 }
             }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always write logic in trigger handler. Dont include trigger events if
  you are not using them.
- In your contact query you are querying all the contacts records which
  might lead to SOQL limits.
- You dont have to necessarily use map to achieve it, you could also
  use list and use "contains" function.

```
        Map < Id, Boolean > accountMap = new Map < Id, Boolean > ();
        Set < Id > accId = new Set < Id > ();
        if (trigger.isBefore && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)) {
            // iterating through all the contacts and getting accountid
            for (Contact con: Trigger.new) {
               if(con.accountId !=null){
                accId.add(con.accountId);
}
            }
            // Querying on account object and fetching those contacts which are primary and belong to above list of account
            for (Contact con: [select id, name, Primary_Contact__c from contact where accountid in: accId and Primary_Contact__c = true]) {
                if (!accountMap.containsKey(con.accountId)) {
                    // map which holds whether account id has primary contact or not
                    accountMap.put(con.accountId, true);
                }
                // Note : We could have simply stored accounts Id in list and used contains function to check same
            }
            for (Contact con: trigger.new) {
                // throwing error (In case using list we would write list.contains(con.accountId)

                if (con.accountId !=null && con.Primary_Contact__c && accountMap.containsKey(con.accountId)) {
                    con.addError('There could be only one Primary contact for each Account');
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from nested for loop there are others problems also.
in conList   you are querying almost all contact of your org and you will likely hit soql rows limit.it will also result in more cpu time processing it.

```
idea should be.
-> store all account id in a set associated with contact in trigger context.
-> query related contact  associated with these accounts and are primary contact.  if yes  store such account in another set e.g.  accwithPrimarycont.
->  as per set created in point 2.  if  your current contact account id  contains  in that set  then primary contact exists and we will throw error.

please refer to untested code you can get generl idea.  you can test it and modify as required.
```

please also create a trigger handler and dont write logic in trigger.

```
trigger AccConTrg on Contact (after insert, before delete, before Insert,before update, after delete) {
  
    //List<Contact> conList = [Select Id, Name, Primary_Contact__c, AccountId from Contact where AccountId != null];
    //store all account id associated with contact in a set
    Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c :trigger.new) {
     if(c.accountid != null)
     accountIdSet.add(c.accountId);

    }

   //  query all related primary contacts and store accountid  in a set  where primary contact exist
   Set<Id> accWithPrimaryCont = new Set<id>;
   for(Contact c : [Select Id, Name, Primary_Contact__c, AccountId from Contact where accountid in :accountIdSet and Primary_Contact__c = true]){

    accWithPrimaryCont.add(c.accountid);
   }
   
    
    
    if(trigger.isBefore && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)){
         for(Contact con: trigger.new){
                 // check if primary contact  and primary contact already exits
                 if(con.Primary_Contact__c &&  accWithPrimaryCont.contains(con.accountid){
                     con.addError('There could be only one Primary contact for each Account');
                 }
             
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you should also add con.account !=null in last if clause as well.

Comment: Thanks for reading.yes we can add null check as extra check  but it will work anyway as accWithPrimaryCont  will have actual accountids  and  accWithPrimaryCont .contains(null)  will be false.

Comment: It will work for sure but if I add con.Account !=null as first condition it will not go inside if clause for those contacts as it will circuit out of and condition and safe execution of whole if clause.